# Web Api Optional Parameters in the middle with attribute routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

So I'm testing some of my routing out with `Postman` and I can't seem to get this call to go through:

**API Function**

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Employees")]
public class CallsController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id:int?}/Calls/{callId:int?}")]
    public async Task<ApiResponse<object>> GetCall(int? id = null, int? callId = null)
    {
        var testRetrieve = id;
        var testRetrieve2 = callId;

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Postman Requests**

http://localhost:61941/api/Employees/Calls DOES NOT WORK

*Error:*

```
{
  "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:61941/api/Employees/Calls'.",
  "MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'Employees' that matches the request."
}
```

http://localhost:61941/api/Employees/1/Calls WORKS

http://localhost:61941/api/Employees/1/Calls/1 WORKS

Any idea why I can't use an optional between my prefix and the custom route? I've tried combining them into one custom route and that doesn't change anything, any time I try to cut out the id it causes problems.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Optional parameters must be at the end of the route template. so what you are trying to do is not possible.

[Attribute routing: Optional URI Parameters and Default Values](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#optional)

you either change your route template

```
[Route("Calls/{id:int?}/{callId:int?}")]
```

or create a new action

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Employees")]
public class CallsController : ApiController {

    //GET api/Employees/1/Calls
    //GET api/Employees/1/Calls/1
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id:int}/Calls/{callId:int?}")]
    public async Task<ApiResponse<object>> GetCall(int id, int? callId = null) {
        var testRetrieve = id;
        var testRetrieve2 = callId;

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    //GET api/Employees/Calls
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Calls")]
    public async Task<ApiResponse<object>> GetAllCalls() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: My votes stock for today is deplenished. :D #SOReadyToHelp.

Comment: It is sad that for the sake of making .NET functionality work, WE need to make changes - even if they do not look logical. Hope MS will retrofit their attribute functionality in future...

Answer (score 4):

I would change the Route to:

```
[Route("Calls/{id:int?}/{callId:int?}")]
```

and add the `[FromUri]` attribute to your parameters:

```
([FromUri]int? id = null, [FromUri]int? callId = null)
```

My test function looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Calls/{id:int?}/{callId:int?}")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetCall([FromUri]int? id = null, [FromUri]int? callId = null)
{
    var test = string.Format("id: {0} callid: {1}", id, callId);

    return Ok(test);
}
```

I can invoke it using:

```
https://localhost/WebApplication1/api/Employees/Calls
https://localhost/WebApplication1/api/Employees/Calls?id=3
https://localhost/WebApplication1/api/Employees/Calls?callid=2
https://localhost/WebApplication1/api/Employees/Calls?id=3&callid=2
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you dont need to specify optional parameter in route

```
[Route("Calls")]
```

or you need to change the route

```
 [Route("Calls/{id:int?}/{callId:int?}")]
 public async Task<ApiResponse<object>> GetCall(int? id = null, int? callId = null)
```

Comment: While that works as a seperate function, I'm looking to encapsulate all 3 of those potential calls under 1 function which if I understand optional routing right it should be possible.